# MS SQL Server SSIS. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

We have an SSIS package hosted in server1. A job in Server 2 is running the SSIS package and load/transform data in Server2. But recently we are receiving the  error below:

> Executed as user: user1. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 11.0.6020.0 for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Started: 6:45:00 AM Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80070020. Server: Serevr1, Package path: \SSISDB\DATABASE1\Project1\Package1.dtsx, Environment reference Id: NULL. Description: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.dll' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS Started: 6:45:00 AM Finished: 6:45:00 AM Elapsed: 0.297 seconds. The package execution failed. The step failed.

This error does not occur  all the time. If we run the package again after the failure it runs successfully. But after few hours or sometimes, few days this error comes again.

***Please Note:*** We are scheduled to run this package every 15 mins.

We couldn't find anything that specifically signifies the error that we are getting. All the links and blogs are not exactly pointing about such situation and error.

Any help regarding this would be really appreciated.

Comment: see this article:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2012/01/19/ssis-error-0x80070020-unable-to-access-the-package-file-make-sure-the-file-exists-and-you-have-permission-to-access-it-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-proces/

Comment: I have already checked this link and it didn't help me. Permissions are all fine, there are no issue with the antivirus. Also we are getting different error  like Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.dll'  sometimes Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.dll' etc.

Comment: It was kind of weird. And I couldn't find out the root cause of the issue. I have checked many suggestions found in the web nothing was could resolve the issue.